# Remove Scopes in Ubuntu for Mobile Devices

Tags: ubuntu-touch, scopes

I realize that I can "hide" a Scope so that it is only visible when I "swipe" up in the Dash (i.e. the "home" screen, during which time all of my Scopes are shown)...

But is it possible to remove/un-install Scopes completely?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so it appears you can remove/un-install most Scopes by searching for them in the Ubuntu Store (as opposed to removing them directly from the Dash)...

I say "most", because unless I am mistaken, some Scopes seem to be "locked" and unable to be removed/un-installed (such as The Weather Channel Scope).